# Use first part of value as header in r

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame generated by `t(summary(raw_data()))`:

[Original data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xgzwd.png)

However, each cell has a prefix of like max, min, mean, etc...  And I would like to remove that prefix from each row and put it at the header.  Is there an easy way to do this in r to get the dataframe to look like this:

[Desired data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzGBh.png)

Also, as far as variables 3 & 18 which are factors.  Those i'm less concerned about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can loop through the columns of the dataset, get the `summary` and then `rbind` the output

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(raw_data, summary))
```

Using a reproducible example

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(iris[1:4], summary))
#              Min. 1st Qu. Median  Mean 3rd Qu. Max.
#Sepal.Length  4.3     5.1   5.80 5.843     6.4  7.9
#Sepal.Width   2.0     2.8   3.00 3.057     3.3  4.4
#Petal.Length  1.0     1.6   4.35 3.758     5.1  6.9
#Petal.Width   0.1     0.3   1.30 1.199     1.8  2.5
```

Comment: Can I inquire about how you came up with that solution?

Comment: @WillKnight Just by guessing how the `summary` will behave when we loop through columns.

Comment: So this works great.  However, when I display the table it has the first three attributes (min, 1st q, median) on the top and the next three on the bottom (mean, 3rd q, and max).  Each 'top' and 'bottom' start with the variables (Sepal..., Petal...) so it's like the data frame is broken up into two rows.  I tried resizing the window and once in a while it will change slightly but not enough to seem directly related.  Is there a surefire way of getting the dataframe to display in one chunk?

Comment: @WillKnight Are you using the `View` in RStudio?  This output is a `matrix` and it works for me without any problem.  If you want to convert to data.frame, `as.data.frame(do.call(rbind,..`